# Mostrar mensagem na tela caso não houver ligação a Internet

Tags: java, android

Criei uma app android que consome dados de uma webservice rest feita em Php, até agora tudo funcionando perfeitamente. O que eu quero agora é mostrar uma mensagem na tela caso não estiver com acesso a Internet ou seja informar ao utilizador para ligar a Internet caso ele se esqueça. Alguém pode me ajudar com isso. obrigado desde já :).

Segue aqui o meu código.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    String myJSON;
    Handler handler;
    private Context context;
    private static final String TAG_RESULTS="resultado";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_ADD ="address";

    JSONArray peoples = null;


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;
    ListView list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        getData();


    }
    public void restartActivity(View view)
    {
        // do your work Here
        Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    public void getData() {

        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    BufferedReader inputStream = null;
                    String result = null;

                    try {

                        URL url = new URL("http://10.127.127.1/ws/aula.php");
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }

                        result = sb.toString();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    finally {
                        try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                    }
                    return result;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                    myJSON=result;
                    showList();
                }
            }
            GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
            g.execute();
        }

        protected void showList(){

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
                peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
                for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
                    JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADD);
                    HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
                    persons.put(TAG_NAME,name);
                    persons.put(TAG_ADD,address);
                    personList.add(persons);
                }


                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this, personList, R.layout.list_item,
                        new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                        new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.address}
                );

                list.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloca esse código dentro do `onPostExecute`

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        if (isConnected == true){
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Conectado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não foi possível conectar. Cheque a internet e tente novamente.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: Coloquei esse código na aplicação e funcionou pela metade, ele notifica quando está conectado a Internet, ate ai tudo bem, mas não estou conseguindo que mostre a mensagem " Não foi possível conectar" porque a aplicação para de funcionar quando não consegue conectar com a Internet. Tem algo de errado com o meu código inicial e não estou conseguindo localizar. Alguma ajuda??

Comment: Esse código tem que rodar no OnCreate antes de chamar o seu getData().

Comment: Como posso fazer isso??

Comment: Eu uso ele no`OnPostExecute` e funciona normal, tanto com como sem internet, @YanikSantos. Mas tenta fazer como o Márcio disse, coloca no `onCreate`. Se possível, posta o erro que dá tb.

Comment: Colocei no OnPostExecute e funcionou bem..Valeu o problema estava era  no meu código inicial.